# javascript return google analytics javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call a javascript function that returns a javascript script.  I want to populate different google analytics codes into the website based on URL.  Whats the best way to do that?  When I try it I have to escape all the " characters which seems like a poor choice.

i.e.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> GetEnvironment()</script>


function GetEnvironment() {
    var url = window.location.host.toLowerCase();
var aw = "<meta name=\"google-site-verification\" ...";


if (url.indexOf('bestpage') != -1) {
    if (url.indexOf('www') != -1)
        return aw;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you're probably looking for a DOM `<script>` element's `.textContent` property I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `String.prototype.match` to reduce `if` statement nesting

```
if (url.match(/.*www.*bestpage.*/)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Here is a great tool to test your regexp: http://regex101.com/#javascript